# Compile linux tool perf for android

Tags: android, linux, perf

I want to compile pref for android device and i did that base on the guide [the guide](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/perf/Documentation/android.txt). One i set NDK environment use Android NDK r9

```
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN=${NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

export NDK_SYSROOT=${NDK}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
```

I run make with tool

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${NDK_TOOLCHAIN} CFLAGS="--sysroot=${NDK_SYSROOT}"
```

I recieve the error, so can you help me?

> Android NDK: NDK_TOOLCHAIN is defined to the unsupported value android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   Android NDK: Please use one of the following values: arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.2 arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.3 mipsel-linux-android-4.6 mipsel-linux-android-4.8 mipsel-linux-android-clang3.2 mipsel-linux-android-clang3.3 x86-4.6 x86-4.8 x86-clang3.2 x86-clang3.3
>   build/core/init.mk:555: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.

Comment: its 2015 im still having the same problem with the latest source also, by d way  did you solve it ?

Comment: @kakeh any luck bro?

Comment: @Hiipe Trinh, did you get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Android bundles the `simpleperf` tool which is almost a drop-in replacement for many usages of `perf`/`linux-tool-perf`.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/simpleperf

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at external/linux-tools-perf/ inside android repository?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/linux-tools-perf/

Comment: you mean to say there is a executable present there ??? i did not find any, what is the point you are trying to make, please help if you have observed any workarround

Answer (score 0):

the error clearly says , you need select appropriate value while exporting ,

export NDK_TOOLCHAIN=${NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-

should be

export NDK_TOOLCHAIN=${NDK}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6

If it dosen't work , i recommend you recheck the overall path which $NDK_TOOLCHAIN contains.

Thanks , Jain

Comment: Thanks,I tried to do that but it doesn't work. $NDK_TOOLCHAIN already includes arm-linux-androideabi- file

Comment: no this is a workout one thinks of when we see the error message, but even if the value is changed to specified the error still persists i dont know why, did any any one worked out ?